# How to find out which encryption/hashing method is used

Tags: encryption, hash

How to find out which encryption/hashing method is used. I have the original password text and its encrypted form,following are the password and its encrypted forms:

Password1 - 2ac9cb7dc02b3c083eb70898e549b63

Newtestpassword1 - 4a43ab1ef64544e13d1c8f03bad63f4

How to identify that which encryption/hashing method is used?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Short of trying everything you can think of, there isn't a definite way to identify this.

Comment: If you could do that, it would make every password encryption useless...

Comment: for all you know those passwords are unencrypted!

Comment: It is MD5 here, but the only way to be sure is looking into the generating source code.

Answer (score 2):

Those are a single, unsalted iteration of MD5, each with a single (but different) hex digit missing:

```
MD5("Password1") = 2ac9cb7dc02b3c0083eb70898e549b63
MD5("Newtestpassword1") = 4a43ab1ef64544e103d1c8f03bad63f4
```

Either you have transcribed them incorrectly, or the algorithm is deliberately dropping 4 bits from near the middle of the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices using hash include some salt in it. So, you can calculate the hash using all the hashes you know (like MD5, SHA1), but you can only discover how it ws generated if you guess:

- how many times it was runned, like how many interactions it had;
- the salt that was used, where it was inserted (beginning? middle? end?), if it was used in every interaction...

So, if it was done correctly, you won't be able to guess it in a resonable time.